# Auto insert today's date based on another cell that is filled via formula

Tags: vba, excel

Using MS Excel, I am making cells from (column A) to be auto generated (as ID) if cells from column B is not blank using the formula `=IF(B4<>"","2018-CI-"&ROWS(A$4:A4),"")` and it is working fine.

what i am trying to do is that i want when a code is generated in a cell of column A1, the date of data entry to be auto inserted in cell of the same row on column D.

So, when the user write a new project name in Col.B, the code will be automatically generated in Col.A in addition to the date of entry to be automatically generated in Col.D. (i want to make the date static, so it does not change if project name is changed because the ID will not change).

i am using this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
xCellColumn = 1
xTimeColumn = 4
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

however, nothing is effected in cells of Col.D, the code works fine if i changed `xCellColumn = 1` to `xCellColumn = 2` which is Col.B (project names in table).

This a picture of table on excel: [image]

Am i doing something wrong? could you help me please?

Comment: Please note that `Dim xRow, xCol As Integer` only defines `xCol As Integer` but `xRow As Variant` if no type is specified. You need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim xRow As Long, xCol As Integer`. Also note that Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle and you must use `Long` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to check if the date was already written and not write it again. So it is only added the first time you add a project name in column B.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TimeColumn = "D"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then 'only trigger on column B

        Dim TargetRow As Range
        For Each TargetRow In Target.Rows 'needed if multiple rows are filled at once eg (copy/paste in col B)
            If Cells(TargetRow.Row, TimeColumn).Value = vbNullString Then 'test if there is already a date
                With Cells(TargetRow.Row, TimeColumn)
                    .Value = Now() 'write the value
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" 'format it
                End With
            End If
        Next TargetRow

    End If

End Sub
```

You probably might want to change `Range("B:B")` into the range where you plan to input the data like `Range("B4:B" & Rows.Count)` to not trigger in the headlines.

Also note that it might happen that in column B multiple rows are inserted eg by copy paste. That's why we need that loop `For Each TargetRow In Target.Rows` so every added line gets its date written.

Also note that we need to use `.NumberFormat` to format the value in the cell. `Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` won't work because it adds the date as text (string) but not as a date value (you can calculate with).

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN documentation of [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function:

> Description Returns a Variant (String) containing an expression
>   formatted according to instructions contained in a format expression.
>   SyntaxFormat(expression [ ,format [ ,firstdayofweek [ ,firstweekofyear
>   ]]] )

This is not what you're trying to achieve, but fret not, Excel already has an inbuilt function to return the current date - it's name is pretty intuitive as well - `date()` if you want date. If you also wanna track time, use `now()` instead

Tested and works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2)), Target) Is Nothing Then

                If IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 2)) Then
                    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Now
                    Target.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                End If
    End If

End Sub
```

*Though I'd probably recommend @PEH's implementation, because it can also track multiple entries which I have not accounted for in my answer*

Comment: I have tried to use (date(), Now()) but still the cells at column D are not effected at all. the question is how to make VBA deal with data that is generated from a formula. i am not sure, but the code is working fine in cells that have to formulas.

Comment: Isn't that because of your `Target.Text <> ""` condition as my edit suggested?

Comment: i have tried it, still nothing is showing up in col.D.

Comment: @Khaledtaj8 check my edit (again). Tested it myself and it works